# Background color bootstrap will not occupy width of fullpage

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsx

I am trying to get the background of a section of my site to be a different color. I've tried making padding and margin 0 as well as a few other things to no avail. I am adding both the CSS and HTML here.

```
<div className="team">
<h1 className="text-center">Our Team</h1>
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 item">
        <div className='circular'>
            <img src={nat} className="img-fluid" alt="team"/>
        </div>
        <div className="des">Natalie</div>
        <div className="text-muted">Manager</div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 item">
        <div className='circular'>
            <img src={rina} className="img-fluid" alt="team"/>
        </div>
        <div className="des">Rina</div>
        <div className="text-muted">Rina Schiller is a software engineer in the investment bank at JPMorgan Chase. She graduated from Hunter college in NYC with a major in digital media and minors in computer science and gender studies. She is very passionate about politics, gender equality, technology, and short hair.</div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 item">
        <div className='circular'>
            <img src={jules} className="img-fluid" alt="team"/>
        </div>
        <div className="des">Jules</div>
        <div className="text-muted">Front End Developer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.team{
    margin: 4em 0;
    position: relative;  
   }
   .team h1{
    color:maroon;
   }
   .team .item{
    position: relative;
   }
   .team .des{
    background: maroon;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    transition:.3s ease-in-out;
    margin-top:3px;
   }

   .teamColor {
       background:pink;
       position: absolute;
       min-height: 100%;
       min-width: 100%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 0 auto;
   }
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure you share all the code you use in a readable way.

Comment: Adding code in a https://codepen.io/pen and sharing the link is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.
Why are you using className instead of class ?
I believe that is your issue

please try this

```css
.team {
 margin: 4em 0;
 position: relative;
}
.team h1 {
 color:maroon;
}
.team .item {
 position: relative;
}
.team .des {
 background: maroon;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top:3px;
 text-align: center;
 transition:.3s ease-in-out;
}
.teamColor {
 background:pink;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 padding: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="team">
 <h1 class="text-center">Our Team</h1>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 item">
   <div class='circular'>
    <img src={nat} class="img-fluid" alt="team"/>
   </div>
   <div class="des">Natalie</div>
   <div class="text-muted">Manager</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 item">
   <div class='circular'>
    <img src={rina} class="img-fluid" alt="team"/>
   </div>
   <div class="des">Rina</div>
   <div class="text-muted">Rina Schiller is a software engineer in the investment bank at JPMorgan Chase. She graduated from Hunter college in NYC with a major in digital media and minors in computer science and gender studies. She is very passionate about politics, gender equality, technology, and short hair.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 item">
   <div class='circular'>
    <img src={jules} class="img-fluid" alt="team"/>
   </div>
   <div class="des">Jules</div>
   <div class="text-muted">Front End Developer</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

here I get the maroon background, not the pink since in your code there is no element with class=teamColor